# Loading command: install (LoadError) cannot load such file -- socket

Tags: sockets, rubygems, bundle, bundler, middleman

I bought new Macbook pro and moved all data from iMac to new Mackbook pro.
then I tried to check the version of bundle with "bundle -v", I got

---

```
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

---

them I tried "gem install bundler", I got

---

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- socket
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

---

It seems like there isn't "socket". 
I reinstalled Homebrew, rben, ruby...
but still I got this error and can't install bundler.
I don't now what to do any more. 
What should I do to fix this????

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ?